# Android: How can I export (or import) a XML-file to Dropbox?

Tags: android, sqlite, import, export, dropbox

I'm trying to make an import-/export-function in my android-app. I store data from a SQLite-database in a XML-string. Instead of storeing it on the SD-card, I want upload it to Dropbox. ... and later I want to get the XML-file from Dropbox to restore the database. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropbox API seems to have what you want. [Check it out](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync)!